# ActionMailer: Default From: address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Googled for this to no avail. Didn't find anything in the API either. I was expecting some kind of class method or configuration option to set it...

So, rather than calling

```
from "my@email.com"
```

for every method, it could be called automatically.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Rails 3

config/environments/development.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'default@development-server.com'
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'default@production-server.com'
```

You can also set this per mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'default@myapp.com'
end
```

## Rails 2

This is not supported by default. But you can achieve this functionality by using the [action_mailer_callbacks](http://github.com/AnthonyCaliendo/action_mailer_callbacks) plugin. Essentially this plugin allows you to add `before` and `after` filters for the `deliver` method.

```
class FooMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  before_deliver do |mail|
    mail.from = "abc@xyz.com"
  end

end
```

**Reference:**

1) [Article](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2009/01/actionmailer-callbacks-in-the-spirit-of-actioncontroller-filters/) discussing the plugin.

### OR

You can monkey patch the `from` method of `ActionMailer::Base`.

Add the code below to your `config\initializers\mail.rb`

```
class ActionMailer::Base
  class_inheritable_hash :default
  def from_with_default(input=nil)
    return from_without_default(input) || default[:from] if input.nil?
    from_without_default(input)
  end
  alias_method_chain :from, :default
end
```

Now you can configure your default value as follows:

config/environments/development.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default = {:from => 'default@development-server.com'}
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default = {:from => 'default@production-server.com'}
```

You can also set this per mailer:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  self.default = {:from => 'default@myapp.com'}
end
```

Answer (score 23):

In Rails 4 you can set this in your environment(s):

```
config.action_mailer.default_options = {
  :from => "foo@bar.com"
}
```

Comment: It seems, `default_options=` has been added in Rails 4 as an alias for `ActionMailer::Base.default`. In Rails 3.2.12 it's not available, though.

Comment: I've updated this answer to refer only to Rails 4, since the code example provided only applies to Rails >= 4.

Answer (score 11):

In Rails 3:

config/environments/development.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'default@development-server.com'
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'default@production-server.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the monkey-patching method that KandadaBoggu suggested. However, it does not work quite right in Rails 2.3.8; you can't override the default. This works, however:

```
def from_with_default(input=nil)
  return instance_variable_set("@from", input) unless input.nil?
  from_without_default || FROM_EMAIL
end
alias_method_chain :from, :default
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 5 & 6

config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}

Answer (score -1):

.. are there changes to rails-6?

`config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: 'noreply@xxx.xx' }`

is not working in production.rb