# Rails3 Global Header Inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a few ActionMailer classes that send out a number of emails....  I want to globally include a header across every single email sent from this Rails app:

Here is a method with the header manually included:

```
class GeneralNotification < ActionMailer::Base

    def test_email(emails)
        subject "Welcome to my email!"
        recipients "somebody@somewhere.com"
        from "chad@awesome.com"

        headers(
            "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}'
        )
    end

end
```

I want that X-SMTPAPI header globally included without modifying every mailer method..

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Chad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame it looks like you're not using Rails 3 which has a new `ActionMailer::Base.default` method which you could use to set this in application.rb. *Edit: I didn't notice you said it was rails 3 in the title. In that case, add this to your config block in config/application.rb:*

```
config.action_mailer.default "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}'
```

For Rails 2.x, you've got two options; use a plugin such as [action_mailer_callbacks](https://github.com/AnthonyCaliendo/action_mailer_callbacks) to define a before_filter style call in an initializer to set the headers, or monkey-path actionmailer to get it to do what you want. Neither are particularly elegant solutions, I'm afraid.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445100/actionmailer-default-from-address) a good example of someone wanting to do the same thing, and how you could monkey-patch AM, but with the from address rather than headers.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I'm using Rails 3 - but after adding this config to my application.rb - it still isn't adding the header.  any suggestions?

Comment: Just had a little try in an app and I couldn't get it to work either using `config.action_mailer.default "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}'`, but could with `ActionMailer::Base.default "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}'`. Hmmm. Odd. I would've thought it'd behave in the same way as the other config options...

Comment: Perfect!! That fixed it for me also.

Comment: So the value of the header is a string (which happens to look like a Ruby 1.9 Hash since its JSON) not a Hash?

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionMailer::Base.default "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}'
```

This will **NOT** work:

```
config.action_mailer.default "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"}' # DOES NOT WORK
```

Comment: In Rails 4, `config.action_mailer.default_options = { "X-SMTPAPI" => '{"category": "Test Category"} }` works for me: [ActionMailer::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-c-default_options-3D)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a superclass which defines this method to simply set the headers:

```
class MailBase < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_email
    # sendgrid headers go here
  end
end
```

Then you make your classes inherit from this class:

```
class MailSub < MailBase
  def test_email
    # email stuff goes here
    super
  end
 end
```

The `super` method call here will call the `test_email` method in the superclass, thereby adding the Sendgrid headers.