# How to change "from" of Rails3 actionmailer by cron?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, gmail, actionmailer

I have tested to send mail an google apps account my_development_account@mydomain.com.
When I send mail, using cron.
and I have used this config/enviroments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true                                             
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mydomain.com", :port => 4649 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'mydomain.com',
    :user_name => "my_development_account@mydomain.com",
    :password => "my_development_account_pass",
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

But I get a new account(new_account@another.my.domain), and send mail from this new account by cron.
and config/enviroments/development.rb for new_account@another.my.domain is here.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true                                             
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "another.my.domain", :port => 4649 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'another.my.domain',
    :user_name => "new_account@another.my.domain",
    :password => "new_account_pass",
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

then the problem happened.
The receiver of my new account's mail still see my_development_account@mydomain.com on from.
I would like to show receivers new_account@another.my.domain on from. How can I solve this?

I tryed restarting cron, sendmail. However this problem is still remain.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445100/actionmailer-default-from-address

Comment: Thank you.
I tried this, but unfortunately, it didn't work that I expected.

Comment: Are you restarting rails when you make these changes?